# Angular - Save referrer after page refresh

Tags: angularjs

Here is the problem:  Our asp site opens to our angular SPA.  In angular we get the referrer in case we need to send them back to it.  Everything is working fine until the user refreshes the SPA site.  Now we've lost the original referrer.  We need to somehow save that referrer even after refresh.  We can't store the referrer in a cookie.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of different options. If you don't want to use a cookie you could write the referrer to local storage. You could also keep the referrer appended to all of your routes so it always stays in the URL.

Comment: We went with angular-local-storage which gave us cookie fallback for IE8.